# Exporting cisco ASA configuration into HP aruba?

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa, cisco-ios, hp, aruba

I wanted to export the configurations from cisco asa firewall into HP aruba ,is there anyway we can make it happen. My company just installed the HP and replaced it with cisco arube, and we have a lot of configurations in cisco and want to export it hp aruba. Is there any process or tool that can be done?

Comment: I think you'll just need to have someone who knows both manually translate the configuration. That's how I've done it for years. Not many people have hp Aruba firewalls. You could ask your hp vendor if they can assist.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is a way to copy config from Cisco to Aruba as both run on different OS.